# Is it a bad idea to learn Ruby and Python simutaneusly?

Tags: python, ruby

I'm learning these [Ruby](http://rubymonk.com) and [Python](http://www.learnpython.org/) interactively and simultaneously. My goal is to learn them at the same time so that I can decide which one I like the most. Is it a bad idea to learn them simutaneusly?

Comment: Just try it.  If it doesn't confuse you, it is fine.

Comment: In the time honoured tradition of self-experimentation and the interests of science. I recommend that you do just so and then report back here with your findings and decide retrospectively whether your idea was good or bad.

Comment: @MattH Well, I get confused from time to time. But I will continue to see how it goes.

Comment: I use my left hemisphere for Ruby, and my right hemisphere for C++. So far, no conflicts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really, but both (Python & Ruby) languages are somehow similar (scripting languages, dynamically typed, with powerful object & class systems). Learning a very different functional language like Haskell or Ocaml (in addition of Ruby or Python) will open more your mind.